# How to log database table value changes programmatically in terms of auditing?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

May be this could be accomplished using a trigger and an audit log table in SQL server. Or perhaps it could be accomplished by overriding the SaveChanges() method in Entity Framework. My concern is how to write the code to get it done and which one will be efficient. Can anybody help me?

Comment: There are certainly people who can help you, yes, however, [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983) Ask us a specific question we can actually answer. Otherwise, if you truly need "help", plenty of the users here have links on their profiles on how you can hire them for consultancy work.

Comment: Actually I need to know that how can I really solve this problem using my coding. Hope that someone has made it work already.

Answer (score 1):

If you log changes through the code, alongside data, you can add additional information to the audit log such as IP, user info, client info, ... and it is really helpful. The downside would be if someone changes data directly via the database you cannot find out what data has changed and the performance of logging data change by audit log table is better. If you just need to capture data change and don't need to find out who and from where data has changed choose the database approach.

Here is an implementation to capture data changes by EF Core:

```
public interface IAuditableEntity
{
}

public class AuditLogEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; }

    public string EntityId { get; set; }

    public string EntityName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EntityPropertyChange> Changes { get; set; }
}

public class EntityPropertyChange
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string OldValue { get; set; }

    public string NewValue { get; set; }
}

public enum ChangeType
{
    Add = 1,
    Edit = 2,
    Remove = 3
}
```

In DbContext:

```
public class RegistryDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public RegistryDbContext(DbContextOptions<RegistryDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) :
        base(options)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public DbSet<AuditLogEntity> AuditLogs { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        CaptureChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        CaptureChanges();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLogEntity>().Property(p => p.UserId).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(36).IsRequired(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLogEntity>().Property(p => p.EntityId).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(36).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLogEntity>().Property(p => p.EntityName).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Ignore(p => p.Changes);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLogEntity>()
            .Property(p => p.Changes).IsUnicode().HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue).IsRequired(false)
            .HasConversion(
                changes => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(changes, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
                }),
                changes => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<EntityPropertyChange>>(changes, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
                }));
    }

    private void CaptureChanges()
    {
        var changes = ChangeTracker
            .Entries<IAuditableEntity>()
            .Where(e =>
                e.State == EntityState.Added ||
                e.State == EntityState.Modified ||
                e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            .Select(GetAuditLogItems)
            .ToList();

        AuditLogs.AddRange(changes);
    }

    private AuditLogEntity GetAuditLogItems(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        var auditEntity = new AuditLogEntity
        {
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            EntityId = entry.Properties.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())?.CurrentValue?.ToString(),
            EntityName = entry.Metadata.Name,
            UserName = _contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Name.ToString(),
        };

        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Added:
                auditEntity.ChangeType = ChangeType.Add;
                auditEntity.Changes = GetChanges(entry.Properties, e => true).ToList();
                foreach (var entityChange in auditEntity.Changes)
                    entityChange.OldValue = null;
                break;

            case EntityState.Modified:
                auditEntity.ChangeType = ChangeType.Edit;
                auditEntity.Changes = GetChanges(entry.Properties, e => e.IsModified).ToList();
                break;

            case EntityState.Deleted:
                auditEntity.ChangeType = ChangeType.Remove;
                break;
        }

        return auditEntity;
    }

    private IEnumerable<EntityPropertyChange> GetChanges(IEnumerable<PropertyEntry> properties,
           Func<PropertyEntry, bool> predicate) => properties
               .Where(predicate)
               .Select(property =>
                   new EntityPropertyChange
                   {
                       PropertyName = property.Metadata.Name,
                       OldValue = property.OriginalValue?.ToString(),
                       NewValue = property.CurrentValue?.ToString()
                   });
}
```

I use `IAuditableEntity` (an empty interface) to mark entities that I want to capture changes.

```
public class CustomerEntity : IAuditableEntity
{
    ...
}
```

You can also use [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) library to capture changes.